# Shutdown /s /t xx doesn't work in my Windows 10 pc

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, powershell-5.0

As the title says, the typical `shutdown /s /t xx` command doesn't work when I run it from a script. Instead of shutting down after `x` seconds, it only runs the `shutdown` part, and ignores the arguments. However, if I type it manually in a Command Prompt window, it executes correctly. I tried running other commands from a script like `ipconfig /all` and I have no problems. Is this a general Windows 10 problem or did I mess up with something on my computer?

P.S. I get the same results with Powershell as well.

Comment: Does single line batch script containing nothing but `shutdown /s /t xx` fail too?

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using in your script, including the surrounding lines before and after.

Comment: @n0rd yes.
@ScottChamberlain it's just `shutdown /s /t 20` and `pause`.

Comment: Look for any extra batch/executable file on the path/current folder called `shutdown`

Comment: @foxidrive There's nothing else in this folder. Just this script with a random name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test this as a diagnostic step.

```
@echo off
"c:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe" /s /t 20
pause
```

Answer (score 3):

Swap out our `/s /t xx` for `-s -t xx`.  That fixed this on my Windows 10 system.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth mentioning Powershell doesn't always play nice with external executables and command line switches/arguments.  Try using:

```
Start-Process shutdown.exe -ArgumentList "/s /t 20"
```

Also, there is `Invoke-Item` which can start a process but I've noticed using `Start-Process`

Reference [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you could use [`Stop-Computer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849839(v=wps.640).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Open notepad

Type in

```
shutdown /s /t 00
```

Save as shutdown.cmd to your desktop

Double click and this should work.

Comment: OP mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237324/shutdown-s-t-xx-doesnt-work-in-my-windows-10-pc/74711582#comment52360253_32237324) that doesnt work